# Updating state and backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm wondering on the best way to do a HTTP PUT with my react application. I have a `Post` component that fetches data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 and displays the data.

I have another component `EditPost` that when clicked on button "Edit" displays a dialog where the user can edit the post. The current data is sent to `EditPost` with a prop.

**Questions**

- Is it best to hold the state in the `Post` component?
- If so, should the update of state and HTTP PUT call be placed in the `Post` component
- How can I update eg. `title` and not the other attributes of `post`?

Post component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Hello from './Hello';
import axios from "axios";

function Post() {
  const [post, setPost] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await axios(
          "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
        );
        setPost(result.data);
      } catch (error) {console.log(error)}
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);



  return(
  <div>
    <h1>{post? post.id: ""}</h1> 
    <h1>{post? post.title: ""}</h1> 
    <h1>{post? post.body: ""}</h1> 
          <EditPost value={post}/>
  </div>)
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Post/>, rootElement);

}
```

Edit Post component:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@material-ui/core/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";

export default function EditPost(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  function handleSubmit() {
    //Do something
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
          Update Post
        </Button>
        <Dialog
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
        >
          <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Update Post</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>Update Post</DialogContentText>
            <TextField
              autoFocus
              margin="dense"
              id="title"
              label="title"
              value={props.value.title}
              fullWidth
            />
            <TextField
              autoFocus
              margin="dense"
              id="body"
              label="body"
              value={props.value.body}
              fullWidth
            />
            <TextField
              autoFocus
              margin="dense"
              id="id"
              label="id"
              value={props.value.id}
              fullWidth
            />
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button color="primary" type="submit">
              OK
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a good practice to handle the state of your form in the component so to do it that way you will need minor modifications on your code.

You are missing a function to handle the values that you want to modify, so you can update it with your service and have the same state on the backend and on the ui.

1. First you need a the variables to store your `title` (and the other props) state, lets make an example with the title.

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
```

You also can set the title as the prop of your data that the parent component is requesting:

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.value.title);
```

2. Then you have to create a function that handles the `title` state.

```
const handleTitle = ( e ) => {
  setTitle(e.target.value);
}
```

3. You have to add this function to you `TextField` component.

```
<TextField
  autoFocus
  margin="dense"
  id="title"
  label="title"
  value={title}
  onChange={handleTitle}
  fullWidth
/>
```

4. When you have all yoiur methods that handle the props of your object, in this case is : `title`, `body` and `id`, you will need a method to submit all this data to your service.

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    const newData = {title: title, id: id, body: body };
    //So here you will submit your data , and when the data is successfully submited you will have to update you Parent state to have the same post data in both components, so you will have to pass your 'setPost' method to EditPost Component to be able to do this:
  props.setPost(newData)
  }
```

So to pass the method to update the current post you have to do something like this in your `EditPost` declaration:

```
 <EditPost  setPost={setPost} value={post}/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 0):

I think It's best if you had parent component which holds the state of post and http callbacks and 2 child component for view and edit.

```
const App = props => {
  // Post state here
  // http callbacks, put get etc.
  return(
    <PostView {...viewProps}/>
    <PostEdit {...editProps}/>
  )
}
```

As for your last question you can use 3rd party form manager such as Formik or react-hooks-form which is helpful mostly because of form validation imo. or you can do it yourself.

If you do it yourself you need to save the inputs state by supplying onChange callback. here's an example:

```
    export default function EditPost(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useStat(false);
  const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState({...props.initialValues})
  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // lift formState to <App/>
    props.onSubmit(formState.title); 
  }

  const handleChange = e => {
     const {name, value} = e.target;
     // can do some validation here before saving the state
     setFormState(prevState => ({...prevState, [name]: value}))
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
          Update Post
        </Button>
        <Dialog
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
        >
          <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Update Post</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>Update Post</DialogContentText>
            <TextField
              autoFocus
              margin="dense"
              id="title"
              label="title"
              value={formState.title}
              name="title"
              onChange={handleChange}
              fullWidth
            />
            <TextField
              autoFocus
              margin="dense"
              id="body"
              label="body"
              name="body"
              value={formState.body}
              fullWidth
            />
            <TextField
              autoFocus
              margin="dense"
              id="id"
              label="id"
              name="id"
              value={formState.id}
              fullWidth
            />
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button color="primary" type="submit">
              OK
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```